# android studio 0.8.1: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Tags: gradle, android-studio, project, synchronization

Ok here's my problem.

1. deleting gradle folder
2. downloading latest gradle 1.10 and 1.12 manually and locating using offline mode
3. open gradle wrapper properties and build.gradle files and editing as mentioned in other blogs
4. Invalidate caches and restart

Nothing worked, but when I set

```
"distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip"
```

in gradle wrapper properties.... it said: "Gradle project syncing.." and I guess it was downloading gradle 1.12 but it didn't download only said "Gradle project syncing.." for a whole day.

Comment: @ChitownDev   my graddle-wrapper properties is set to:      distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
 and  my build.gradle file is set to:                         dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
}          the problem is when i open android studio ..... and the bottom  it shows ( Gradle: Download "http://services.gradle.org/distribuitions/gradle-1.10.zip" )

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and tried many of the posted solutions to no avail. In the end, I actually just did build -> Clean Project and it worked.